# php while within array

Tags: php, arrays, json, while-loop

I have to populate a json with PHP.
I have this structure:

```
$request = array(
      "api_uid" => "000000", 
      "api_key" => "xxxxxx", 

      "lista_articoli" => array(

      //loop 


      array(
"nome" => "Acconto",
      "descrizione" => "Acconto per la festa del " .$datafesta,
      "prezzo_lordo" => $importo,
      "cod_iva" => 0 
        )

   // end loop
```

I try to use while inside array, but it's an error:

```
while($row = $tipologia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

      array("nome" => $row['nome'],
      "descrizione" => $row['desc'],
      "prezzo_lordo" => $row['prezzo_lordo'],
      "cod_iva" => 0 
        ),
                     }
```

How can i loop my data in correct way inside array?

Comment: you can not loop in inside array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't loop inside array.You need to create array and assign value to them by keys in loop.Try like below :

```
while ($row = $tipologia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $request['lista_articoli'][] = [
        'nome' => $row['nome'],
        'descrizione' => $row['desc'],
        'prezzo_lordo'] => $row['prezzo_lordo'],
        'cod_iva' => 0,
    ];
}
```

Comment: This will just keep overriding the values, you probably want to add an array on each iteration.

Comment: no that is not what he asked...He just showed one array and assigning inside array which is wrong..

Comment: Thank you, but I can not understand  where to put your code into my structure

Comment: you can put anywhere where is appropriate..Please accept the answer by click the tick mark @frwebdev

Comment: i try to put your code inside my loop area, but i still have the same error, because i have array right after ...$request = array(....
Sorry for my low level in php

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)
I am trying to put your code inside my array...
$request = array(....
Unlike how do I enter the result of your code in my array?

Comment: it was a wrong **]** after 'prezzo_lordo' in your code